# Embed iFrame in Google presentation

Tags: google-slides, iframe

Is it possible to embed a website in an iFrame inside a Google presentation in Google Docs/Drive?

I tried it, looked through all menus and submenus but couldn't find an option which lets me embed web-content other than videos from YouTube.

I know that its possible in PowerPoint but for once I'd like to go with an online-only solution.

Comment: Did you try it yet?

Comment: yeah, doesn't work afaik.

Comment: I suggest you include that in [your post](http://superuser.com/posts/586450/edit) because it reads like "can this be done, I don't want to try it, please do my work!" where clearly you have done your work/research and tried it! :) This may help you get better answers too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time you can not do that. However Google is constantly updating this stuff, so it may be possible in the future.

Comment: 8 years on, I think this is still not possible.

Answer (score -3):

i found a way on http://slides.com/. You can add iframe in your presentation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: today slides.com (or rather reveal.js) is still the only way to embed iframes in slides